# Some PHP Code is breaking the rest of the page

Tags: php

I have an odd problem. Basicly my page works fine however after a small bit of php, everything after those lines dont load too the page.

```
<?php


//GET SCHOOLS
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `school`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$numschools = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo "<select id=\"schoolselect\" class=\"schoolselect\" value=\"Select School\">
<option id='selectschool' value = \"select\" name=\"select\">Select A School</option>

";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
{

    $school = $result['id'];
    echo "<option value = \"$school\" name=\"$school\">".$school ."</option>";


}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

everything before that works, the php part works but anything after that echo "select" doesnt

any help would be amazing

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see if you get any errors from your script.

Comment: Also, if you're only selecting the 'id' field from the table, you'll only get select options with numeric data (assuming 'id' is an auto-increment field in your mysql table). You might want to change that to something like "select id,name from school"

I agree with JamWaffles though, you should check your web server error log for any details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never call `die(mysql_error())` inside a fetch loop.  `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `FALSE` when no more rows are available, so when the last row is reached, `die()` is called and your script will terminate leaving the `</select>` unclosed.  You won't get an error message, but you'll be left with incomplete HTML that won't render properly in the browser.

```
// Don't call die(mysql_error()) in a fetch loop!
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $school = $result['id'];
    echo "<option value = \"$school\" name=\"$school\">".$school ."</option>";
}
```

Comment: It's refreshing to see `mysql_error()` used *too much* instead of the usual *not at all*.

Comment: Thanks, That was the soluition. :) Will accept answer when time is up :)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your script is `or die()`ing inside the `<select>` tag, which is invisible in the browser.

View the page's source, and you'll most likely see a PHP fatal error or a `die` message at the end.

EDIT: Or read Michael's answer, cuz I forgot how things worked. Duh :p At least this answer will help you find related problems in the future.